# Workbox precache doesn't precache

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, sw-precache, workbox-window

I'm attempting to implement workbox to precache image and video assets on a website.

I've created a service worker file. It appears to be successfully referenced and used in my application. The service worker:

```js
import { clientsClaim, setCacheNameDetails } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute, addRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

const context = self; // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals

setCacheNameDetails({ precache: 'app' });

// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals, no-underscore-dangle
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

context.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('dive').then((cache) => {
      console.log(cache);
    }),
  );
});

context.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  console.log('sw active');
});

context.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
  console.log(event.request.url);
});

context.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const { type, payload } = data;

  if (type === 'cache') {
    payload.forEach((url) => {
      addRoute(url);
    });

    const manifest = payload.map((url) => (
      {
        url,
        revision: null,
      }
    ));

    console.log('attempting to precache and route manifest', JSON.stringify(manifest));
    precacheAndRoute(manifest);
  }
});

context.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
```

The application uses workbox-window to load, reference and message the service worker. The app looks like:

```js
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';

workbox = new Workbox('/sw.js');

workbox.register();
workbox.messageSW({
  type: 'cache',
  payload: [
    { url: 'https://media0.giphy.com/media/Ju7l5y9osyymQ/giphy.gif' }
  ],
});
```

This project is using vue with vue-cli. It has a webpack config which allows plugins to be sent added to webpack. The config looks like:

```js
const { InjectManifest } = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: path.join(__dirname, 'lib/services/Asset-Cache.serviceworker.js'),
        swDest: 'Asset-Cache.serviceworker.js',
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

I can see messages are successfully sent to the service worker and contain the correct payload. BUT, the assets never show up in Chrome dev tools cache storage. I also never see any workbox logging related to the assets sent via messageSW. I've also tested by disabling my internet, the assets don't appear to be loading into the cache. What am I doing wrong here?

I found the workbox docs to be a little unclear and have also tried to delete the message event handler from the service worker. Then, send messages to the service worker like this:

```js
workbox.messageSW({
  type: 'CACHE_URLS',
  payload: { urlsToCache: [ 'https://media0.giphy.com/media/Ju7l5y9osyymQ/giphy.gif'] },
});
```

This also appears to have no effect on the cache.

Comment: Is there any chance you could deploy this to a public URL and share that? I'd like to reproduce and debug this.

Comment: @JeffPosnick - thanks for getting back to me. I messed with this a bit more and it looks like calling precacheAndRoute from inside the message listener just doesn't do anything. Moving the same call outside the handler works fine. I put together a little git repo https://github.com/joelongstreet/workbox-doesnt-precache and published my project here - https://joelongstreet.com/workbox-doesnt-precache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `precache` portion of `precacheAndRoute()` works by adding `install` and `activate` listeners to the current service worker, taking advantage of the [service worker lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle). This will effectively be a no-op if the service worker has already finished installing and activating by the time it's called, which may be the case if you trigger it conditionally via a `message` handler.

We should probably warn folks about this ineffective usage of `precacheAndRoute()` in our Workbox development builds; I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2695) to track that.

Comment: Thank you for creating an issue to update the docs. I think your link has an extra zero at the end of it.